# Sorting by value in rocksdb

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java, okvs

Rocksdb allows to sort the records by keys but I want to sort them by value. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answers the question :)

Answer (score 3):

RocksDB doesn't support secondary index directly, but you can build your own secondary index on top of RocksDB. Here is an very simple example using [`BatchWrite`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations#atomic-updates):

```
// create 2 ColumnFamily, one for data, one for index
Status s = db->CreateColumnFamily(cf_options, "Data", &data_handle);
Status s = db->CreateColumnFamily(cf_options, "Index", &index_handle);

// Use batch to guarantee consistency between data and index
WriteBatch batch;
batch.Put(data_handle, "key1", "value1");
batch.Put(index_handle, "value1", "key1");

db->Write(WriteOptions(), &batch);

std::string result;
s = db_->Get(ReadOptions(), data_handle, "key1", &result);
// index ColumnFamily is sorted by value
s = db_->Get(ReadOptions(), index_handle, "value1", &result);
```

This is an over simplified example, in reality you need to handle lots of other things like duplicated key or value, space amplification, etc.
There're existing secondary-indices implementations for your reference, like:
[mokuroku](https://github.com/nlfiedler/mokuroku), [myrocks](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/myrocks-and-index-only-scans/), etc.